# C# tag links on "Real-time" page do not work as intended

Tags: bug, tags, stackexchange.com, realtime-questions

A little problem with special chars escaping.

[c#](/questions/tagged/c%23) links on [the page with real-time questions](https://stackexchange.com/questions?tab=realtime) lead to the following address: `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c#` where `#` is an url anchor, and not a part of tag name, resulting in [c](/questions/tagged/c) tag page.

While correct address is: `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%23`

This applies to ru.stackoverflow.com as well.

Note that [hot questions page](https://stackexchange.com/) works fine.